# How to make a div change when clicked and stay changed afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div so that when it is clicked it grows in size and changes colour to attach to another div. The code I have so far is:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
            <a href="homepage.html" onmousedown="javascript:(btn=document.getElementById('btnhome')).className = (btn.className  == 'clicked') ? '' : 'clicked';"><div id="btnhome">Home</div></a>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
    #btnhome.clicked{
       background-color:#ff9014;
       height:50px;
    }
```

I have got this far, which does make the div change when it is clicked, but it does not make the div stay that way after being clicked which is what I am hoping to achieve.

What I have is a orange div containing text and above that is where the buttons are (I am using divs as buttons). When clicked I want the button to grow in size and connect to the other div to show that is the page that the user is on. So I want the button when clicked to load the page and then stay the increased size as a way of seeing which page you are on.

Comment: Change `(btn.className  == 'clicked') ? '' : 'clicked';` to `"clicked"` you are changing it back to original on second click

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to JavaScript, could you be more specific what to change please

Comment: Do you want the homepage.html to load when the button is clicked?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You want to affect the div...so why are you adding code / classes to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Don't toggle the class name.  Always set to clicked.

```
onmousedown="javascript:(btn=document.getElementById('btnhome')).className = 'clicked';"
```

Comment: the div still just changes back to normal after being clicked

Comment: Following the link will lead to a new page which obviously doesn't preserve anything on this page.  Change the href to '#' to see what happens if you don't load a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like. If you don't want the new page to load.

```
 <a href="homepage.html" onmousedown="javascript:(btn=document.getElementById('btnhome')).className = 'clicked'; return false;"><div id="btnhome">Home</div></a>
```

If you want the new page to load then do it like:

```
 <a href="homepage.html" onmousedown="javascript:(btn=document.getElementById('btnhome')).className = 'clicked'; this.href= this.href + '?btn=clicked'"><div id="btnhome">Home</div></a>
```

and add the following to all the pages (probably in header etc)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var QueryString = function () {
   // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
   // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
   var query_string = {};
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       // If first entry with this name
       if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
          query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
         // If second entry with this name
      } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
         var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
         query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
         // If third or later entry with this name
      } else {
         query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
      }
   } 
    return query_string;
  } ();

if(QueryString.btn === 'clicked'){
    document.getElementById('btnhome')).className = 'clicked';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dd").click(function(){
$("#dd").css("background-color","pink");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dd">Click the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

just copy and paste, this example uses jquery